# Ruby Spinach Html Result Page

Tags: rspec, bdd, spinach

I've just started looking at the Spinach BDD framework and one thing I'd really like to do is to have a results HTML page generated similar to the rspec options: 
--format html
--out rspec_results.html

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this with Spinach?
Thanks!

Comment: I found that someone created a formatter.
https://github.com/codegram/spinach/issues/98

Answer (score 0):

I found that someone created a formatter.
https://github.com/codegram/spinach/issues/98